# Does Enterprise BU stay connected when turning on Multi-Org?

Tags: marketing-cloud, multi-org

When Multi-org is enabled in an account that has the enterprise parent Business Unit connected to a Salesforce org. Will that connection remain?

I've read in documentation that this is the case.

"Can I Enable Multi-Org for an Existing Account?

Yes. Upgrading an existing Enterprise 2.0 account is possible, but any previously connected business unit must be manually reconnected. The top-level (parent) account remains connected."

Source:https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_faqs_for_multi_org.htm&type=5

However I have heard that with the new connector that the connection will be disconnected when Multi-org is enabled.

Can someone please confirm? I need to know if I have to reconnect the Business Unit and the impact of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reconnect, and connect each child BU as necessary. Once multi-org is installed, it can't be reversed.

Your main impact might be on any Journeys that using SF as a source. But if you are using SQL to inject into the Journey then these will be safe (unless you have changed the name of your SF objects)

Comment: Hey iManage, thanks for your comment. I thought that would be the case with Child Business Units. However, will the top parent Business Unit be disconnected? I have the synchronized Data Extensions in that business unit, so will they disappear in when enabling Multi-Org?

Comment: Hi Mark, each time i've performed a multi-org migration, I have disconnected the parent and reconnected it; be it out of habit in testing and troubleshooting. Once you disconnect the Sync Data Extensions will disappear. 

Once you reconnect, and resync your objects then they will appear again